# Improve performace of JAX-RS application

Tags: java, performance, rest, jax-rs, websphere-liberty

I've been working on a `JAX-RS` application for Java Restful Webservices.

The application is experiencing a performance issue with huge load.

Normally it take around 400 milliseconds (0.4 seconds) to serve a request but when I replicate the same request for 1000 times the time for serving each request increased to 30000 milliseconds (30 seconds).

Its fairly simple application using: `jax-rs`, `CDI Injection`, `jaxb` and `JDBC`.

Server is `IBM WAS with Liberty Profile`.

Deployed on `docker` container with 2 pods/nodes.

Ho do I increase the performance for this application?

Comment: By analyzing the bottlenecks and fixing them.

Comment: As Jared mentions, please provide more details. Performance tuning is a complex task, and you can read about some theoretical concepts here: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/. As a place to start, I agree about checking [verbosegc](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/Major_Tools-Garbage_Collection_and_Memory_Visualizer_GCMV.html) and also gathering [thread dumps](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/Major_Tools-IBM_Thread_and_Monitor_Dump_Analyzer_TMDA.html) during the issue. You may also consider using the requestTiming feature with a large threshold.

Answer (score 3):

Kishor,

There have been several performance improvements for throughput related to the thread pool in later releases of WebSphere Liberty.  Your question does not provide information about what level of WebSphere Liberty you are using.  Additionally there have been several performance improvements in the JAX-RS function in WebSphere Liberty that also may be beneficial.

As was suggested, you need to determine what is causes the slowdown by analyzing the bottlenecks.  Usually it is a resource of some kind; for example, network, CPU, memory, disk, lock, etc.  Running with verbose GC is a good place to start and taking a look at the garbage collection activity.  If your heap is not configured appropriately for the load that you are trying to do, garbage collection pauses may cause your problem, but there are also many other possibilities as well.  It is a good one to rule out right away since it is easy to do that analysis.

If you provide your WebSphere Liberty version number that will help people give you more information about possible things that could help.

Comment: The version numbers don't matter. It's not related to `WAS`, but his own code. You use a profiler to find the hotspots, verbose GC is a **bad** place to start, since it produces a lot of output and doesn't tell you the root of the problem. Not to mention you're assuming that GC is the problem.

Comment: I was stating verbose GC is a place to start to see if memory is the constraining resource.  People configure their heap sizes wrong all the time and get limited throughput because they are doing garbage collections all the time.  I am not assuming GC is the problem, just stating it as one of the possibilities.